# missing corpus error in textblob using django

Tags: python, django, textblob

I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.8 and my server is Apache on Linux Ubuntu. I have a JSON file with 23000 tweets in it. I want to classify the tweets according to predefined categories. But when I run the code, it throws `MissingCorpusError at /` and suggests:

To download the necessary data, simply run

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

I already have the latest corpora for TextBlob. Still, I get the error.

My views.py is as follows:

```
def get_tweets(request):
    retweet = 0
    category = ''
    sentiment = ''
    tweets_data_path = STATIC_PATH+'/stream.json'
    tweets_data = []
    tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
    for line in tweets_file:
        try:
            tweet = json.loads(line)
            tweets_data.append(tweet)
        except:
            continue
    subs = []
    for l in tweets_data:
        s = re.sub("http[\w+]{0,4}://t.co/[\w]+","",l)
        subs.append(s)
    for t in subs:
        i = 0
        while i < len(t):
            text = t[i]['tweet_text']
            senti = TextBlob(text)
            category = cl.classify(text)
            if senti.sentiment.polarity > 0:
                sentimen = 'positive'
            elif senti.sentiment.polarity < 0:
                sentimen = 'negative'
            else:
                sentimen = 'neutral'
            if text.startswith('RT'):
                retweet = 1
            else:
                retweet = 0
            twe = Tweet(text=text,category=category,
                sentiment=sentimen, retweet= retweet)
            twe.save()
            i = i+1
    return HttpResponse("done")
```

Comment: Please post the structure of the json. And rewrite the while loop as `for ti in t` . How many tweets are there for each subs?

Comment: altogether, there are 23689 tweets. should i post the structure of json file or a particular tweet?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
When i download nltk_data it was placed to /root/nltk_data/, when I copy this nltk_data folder to /var/www/ it works OK.

```
$ sudo cp -avr nltk_data/ /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the dame problem. I am using anaconda and it worked for me.
This might help:

http://www.nltk.org/data.html

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/nltk

$ pip3 install -U textblob

$ python3 -m textblob.download_corpora

Comment: $ pip install -U textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora